# Lodash Operation sometimes fails to complete in Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, lodash

I'm building a trading bot and I have this code which takes an array of arrays of 5 (API allows 5 price requests at a time). For each of these currencies, [this api](https://github.com/askmike/whaleclub) does an API call and retrieves results with a promise. In the promise I forEach through each currency returned, calculate the average of the prices and then save it to MongoDB.

```
Market.prototype.fetchPrices = function(currencyPairs){
  var self = this
  let currencyPairGroups = chunkBy5(currencyPairs)
  _.forEach(currencyPairGroups, function(currencyPairGroup){
    wc.price(currencyPairGroup).then(function(res){
      let pairs = Object.keys(res);
      _.forEach(pairs, function(pair) {
        let currentObj = res[pair]
        currentObj.pair = pair
        currentObj.mid = _.mean([currentObj.bid, currentObj.ask])
        console.log('Before saving ' + '\n' +
          'this is the pair ' + currentObj.pair + '\n' +
          'and this is the bid ' + currentObj.bid + '\n' +
          'and this is the ask ' + currentObj.ask + '\n' +
          'and this is the mid ' + currentObj.mid + '\n' +
          'is the mid a NaN? ' + isNaN(currentObj.mid) + '\n')
        savePrice(currentObj)
        self.emit('emitPrice', currentObj)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Almost always, this works perfectly. Sometimes, however, the currentObj.mid gets passed as NaN and the save validation to Mongoose fails. The console.log looks like this.

```
this is the pair USD-MXN
and this is the bid 17.90732
and this is the ask 17.91332
and this is the mid NaN
is the mid a NaN? true
```

I feel like it's an async issue, but I don't think anything in my promise is async. Also, don't know why it works almost every other time. Don't even know what question to ask to figure this out.

Comment: as `.mid` is calculated directly from `.bid` and `.ask` - it's highly unlikely to be an async issue - what is `_.mean`? why not just use `(.ask + .bid) / 2`?

Comment: try `.mean([Number(currentObj.bid), Number(currentObj.ask)])` - though, you'd think lodash would be doing that so it's probably a redundant suggestion - note: no, lodash does not appear to be doing this very basic "sanitisation" of data - perhaps your results for bid and ask are (in some cases) strings?